# O que são Feature Queries no CSS? Como se faz o uso delas e para que servem?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tenho ouvido bastante o termo ***Feature Queries*** quando se fala em CSS3.

Mas o que são e para que servem as `Feature Queries`?

Como se aplica isso no CSS dos projetos?

Comment: Da uma lida nesse link aqui amigo: [https://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-sobre-css-media-types-e-media-queries/28268](https://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-sobre-css-media-types-e-media-queries/28268)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a especificação da W3C, "*[features querys](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-supports)*" são:

> The ‘@supports’ rule is a conditional group rule whose condition tests
> whether the user agent supports CSS property:value pairs. Authors can
> use it to write style sheets that use new features when available but
> degrade gracefully when those features are not supported. CSS has
> existing mechanisms for graceful degradation, such as ignoring
> unsupported properties or values, but these are not always sufficient
> when large groups of styles need to be tied to the support for certain
> features, as is the case for use of new layout system features.

em tradução livre:

> A regra '@supports' é uma regra de grupo condicional que afirma que o
> agente do usuário suporta CSS um par "propriedade/valor". Os
> autores podem usá-lo para escrever estilo quando não estiverem
> disponíveis. O CSS possui mecanismos existentes para degradação
> normal, como ignorar propriedades ou valores não suportados, mas eles
> não são necessariamente suficientes quando grupos grandes de estilos
> precisam estar ligados ao suporte de determinados recursos, como é o
> caso do uso de novos recursos do sistema de layout.

## Na prática

Com @supports, podemos escrever uma instrução condicional (a.k.a feature query), que será levada em conta se e somente se a propriedade CSS for suportada pelo navegador.

Vale a pena frisar que este recurso não está disponível para o IE 11 e anteriores. Fonte: [CanIUse CSS Feature Querie](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries)

O uso do @support é semelhante ao media queries

```
@supports (background-blend-mode: hue) {
   /* as regras definidas aqui serão aplicadas
     se o browser suportar o  background-blend-mode: hue */
}
```