# Como posso verificar se o navegador suporta HTML 5?

Tags: html5, validação

Como fazer para verificar se o navegador suporta HTML 5?

Por exemplo, gostaria de definir um campo do formulário como requerido. Posso utilizar o parâmetro `required`:

```
<input type="text" required>
```

Mas vi que [`required` funciona apenas a partir do HTML 5](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required). Se o navegador do cliente não suportar esta versão, o campo pode não funcionar como desejado.

Assim, existe alguma maneira de eu verificar se o cliente atual suporta HTML 5 para que quando não suportar eu forçar esta validação via JavaScript?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=required

Comment: Leai aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30504/tem-como-fazer-feature-detection-pra-css e aqui tb https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316656/o-que-s%C3%A3o-feature-queries-no-css-como-se-faz-o-uso-delas-e-para-que-servem

Comment: to pode tentar usar o modernizr

Comment: Carlos, não entendi bem porque a pergunta levou vários negativos, então tentei editá-la buscando clarear melhor o problema. Veja se não acabei alterando algo importante da pergunta original.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 não é exatamente um recurso que você pode verificar ou não se está presente. HTML5 foi o nome dado a uma série métodos, componentes e tags adicionados a linguagem HTML que foram recebendo suporte gradativamente pelos browsers.

Algo que acho importante mencionar é que todos os principais browsers aceitam as features HTML5 e já o fazem a bastante tempo então não entendi muito bem o motivo de você querer fazer essa verificação em vez de simplesmente assumir que o browser tem a validação e pronto. Deixe os browsers antigos morrerem.

Outro tópico digno de ser mencionado é: Não se deve confiar em nenhuma validação apenas no front-end, são simples de burlar até mesmo pelos inspetores.

Com isso dito, você e sabendo que HTML5 não é algo que da pra verificar se está lá ou não, o que você pode fazer é verificar diretamente o método que precisa.

No caso da validação, você pode selecionar um formulário em sua página `document.querySelector('form')` acessar o `__proto__` (onde ficam todos os métodos nativos daquele elemento e verificar se o método `checkValidity` (que é o nome do método que faz a validação do HTML) existe ou não.

```
if (typeof document.querySelector('form').__proto__.checkValidity) === 'function' {
// O formulário tem validação nativa 
} else { 
// O formulário não tem validação nativa
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O bom sempre é olhar na documentação sobre o recurso e o suporte dele pelos navegadores.
Aqui está uma lista dos principais recursos do HTML5 e o nível de suporte pelos navegadores: http://html5readiness.com/ 
Caso você queira adaptar o seu código para uso em navegadores mais antigos é necessário que você crie um script para isso ou utilize uma biblioteca já criada para tratamento de incompatibilidade com navegadores como o Modernizr ou o IE7.js por exemplo.
O Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/) é uma pequena biblioteca javascript que

Este link explica bem sobre sua questão: https://medium.com/@eduagni/html5-css3-suporte-dos-navegadores-e-t%C3%A9cnicas-de-compatibilidade-186d6c876434

Comment: 1) Há uma diferença entre saber quais versões suportam o recurso e se a versão do cliente suporta o recurso; 2) Já que cita que a biblioteca Modernizr pode resolver o problema, poderia dar um exemplo concreto de solução especialmente para o atributo `required`?